# Error ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 al conectar a MongoDB utilizando Mongoose o NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Al tratar de conectar la db en localhost surge el siguiente error**

[image]

**A Continuación dejo los archivos**

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");

const config = require("./server/config");

//Database
require("./database");

const app = config(express());

//Starting server
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log("Server on port", app.get("port"));
});
```

**database.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { database } = require("./keys");

mongoose
  .connect(database.URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
  .then((db) => console.log("DB is connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

**keys.js**

```
module.exports = {
  database: {
    URI: "mongodb://localhost/imgshare",
  }
};
```

**config.js**

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  //Settings
  app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

  return app;
};
```

Estuve googleando y no encontré alguna solución alguna recomendación de como poder resolver este problema? La bd está conectada y activa

[[image: Captura de la base de datos2]

Comment: La URI está mal configurada. A partir de la versión 12.x de Node, apuntar a `localhost` en cualquier recurso de red, realiza la conversión a IPv6 si esta está disponible en tu adaptador. Cambia la URI por `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/imgshare` y comenta el resultado

Comment: En efecto era eso, muchisimas gracias!!! @MauricioContreras

Comment: Voy a publicar una respuesta. Editaré el titulo de tu pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Al conectar desde NodeJS (Mongoose) a MongoDB usando como URI de conexión lo siguiente:

> `mongodb://localhost/db_name`

La conexión no se establece y provoca el siguiente error:

> `NetworkServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017`

El problema no es de Mongoose, es de NodeJS. A partir de la versión 17 de Node, [se favorece el uso de IPv6 sobre IPv4](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/39987), de hecho el problema no es que se *favorezca*, simplemente se toma la resolución tal como la devuelve el *resolver* DNS del adaptador de red. Es por ello que te da el error de conexión, ya que es muy probable que el [*binding* IP](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/) de MongoDB esté configurado por defecto para usar solamente IPv4.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Existen dos soluciones al problema, la primera es muy simple e implica cambiar la URI de conexión en tu aplicación. De esta forma obligas al driver de conexión de MongoDB a usar IPv4.

Así, la URI se debería ver de la siguiente forma:

> `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db_name`

Otra opción es establecer el *binding* IP de MongoDB para que el recurso `localhost` no solo use el espacio IPv4 sino que también pueda usar el especio IPv6. Para ello debes realizar cambios en el [archivo de configuración](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file) de MongoDB en tu implementación local y establecer el siguiente parámetro: [`net.ipv6`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.ipv6) a `true`, por ejemplo:

```js
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost
  ipv6: true  // <- esto habilita IPv6
```

En Windows, el archivo de configuración (`mongod.cfg`) para MongoDB 5.x se ubica, por lo general, en:

> `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin`

En Linux (Debian based) el archivo de configuración de MongoDB se encuentra, por lo general, en:

> `/etc/mongod.cfg`

Recuerda usar permisos de administrador o de super user para editarlo. Además, debes reiniciar tu servidor de MongoDB para que se apliquen los cambios.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.