# Se me apaga el servidor de node

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, servidor, mongoose

Tengo un problema y es que el servidor deja de correr luego de unos 30 segundos de ser inicializado, al principio funciona perfecto y puedo visitar el localhost en el navegador y recibo respuesta, pero luego de pasados esos segundos me aparece el siguiente error y el servidor deja de funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que no puede conectarse a tu mongo. Has comprobado que esté levantado y funcionando?

Comment: Si, el error parece ser que intenta durante 30 segundos conectarse a la BD, y como no puede salta el error.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 al conectar a MongoDB utilizando Mongoose o NodeJS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547837/error-econnrefused-127017-al-conectar-a-mongodb-utilizando-mongoose-o-nodejs)