# Conexión a una base de datos con MongoDB y express js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos de mongoDB, pero siempre me da un error al momento de ver el funcionamiento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado muchas maneras maneras pero no encuentro la solución.
Acá mi código de conexión

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MONGO_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/autentication";

const db = async () => {
    await mongoose
        .connect(MONGO_URL)
        .then(() => console.log("DB funcionando"))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};

module.exports = db;
```

autentication es el nombre que le di a mi base de datos

Comment: No es un error, es una advertencia (Warning) diciendo que va a haber un cambio en una versión futura y te da algunas opciones para prepararte para ese cambio, utilizar `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)` o `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true)`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 al conectar a MongoDB utilizando Mongoose o NodeJS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547837/error-econnrefused-127017-al-conectar-a-mongodb-utilizando-mongoose-o-nodejs)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato es un error, aunque bien visto lo de la advertencia previa al error. El problema no es de Mongoose ni de MongoDB, ni siquiera es de Express, el problema es NodeJS y un cambio en la forma de resolución de `host`. Antiguamente se daba preferencia a `IPv4`, pero ahora no se da esa preferencia y simplemente se usa el host que el resolver DNS (dispositivo lógico de conexión de red) informe durante la petición. Si el resolver informa primero `IPv6` pues ese se usará, aunque `IPv4` también esté disponible. Ya he enlazado la respuesta, ya que la pregunta es duplicada. Saludos

Comment: Al parecer es un conflicto de versiones, reemplace el localhost con el ip y funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de utilizar

```
const URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/autentication';
```

Utiliza

```
const URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/autentication';
```

La ip 127.0.0.1= localhost, Pero en mongo al parecer da un error. Saludos