# Problemas para realizar conexion a MONGODB en mi proyecto

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, backend

Hola estoy tratando de usar por primera vez MongoDB + Studio 3T en mi proyecto, pero cuando trato de realizar la conexion me salta error. anteriormente no me reconocia el comando "mongod" el CMD ya lo solucione, y en el FireWall de Windows agregue una nueva regla para que no haya problema con el puerto. luego probe en "mongod.cfg", vi a uno del foro, que le agrego

net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
ipv6: true

paso el error que me surge cuando quiero hacer la conexion:

PS C:\Users\Hollenstein\Documents\Franco\negocio\negocio-backend> npm run dev

> negocio-backend@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js

[nodemon] 3.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
(node:6924) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option: useNewUrlParser has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major
version
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6924) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useUnifiedTopology is a deprecated option: useUnifiedTopology has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next
major version
Estoy en el puerto 4000
Error al conectar a la base de datos: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\Hollenstein\Documents\Franco\negocio\negocio-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:809:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\Hollenstein\Documents\Franco\negocio\negocio-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:11) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y paso el codigo, que trate de todas las formas pero al parecer es la configuracion del mongo, la verdad no sabria:

index.js

```
introducir el código aquí
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';
import './database';

const app = express();

app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 4000);

app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
console.log("Estoy en el puerto "+app.get('port'));
});

 // Herramientas extras
 app.use(morgan('dev'));
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../public")));
 app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
res.send("puerto")
})
```

y el codigo de database

```
introducir el código aquí
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/KioskoDB';

async function main() {
try {
    await mongoose.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    const connection = mongoose.connection;

    connection.once('open', () => {
        console.log("¡Conexión exitosa!");
    });

    connection.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error("Error de conexión:", err);
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al conectar a la base de datos:", error);
}
}

main();
```

Comment: Cambia la cadena de conexión, donde dice `localhost`, escribe: `127.0.0.1`. Intenta nuevamente la conexión y comenta el resultado.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 al conectar a MongoDB utilizando Mongoose o NodeJS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547837/error-econnrefused-127017-al-conectar-a-mongodb-utilizando-mongoose-o-nodejs)

Comment: Se soluciono, gracias pa  'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/KioskoDB'